# cannnot able to perform update on navigation in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i want to Create a Simple Database in wp7.In Mainpage i simply add the Records in  database and i have another button **view** which is used to navigate to another page where gridview control is there that can display the data from database that is already done.In the second page i have two Buttons delete and update and i have a textbox where user can enter the id and based on that *id* the delete and update process can be done.i done the delete operation but i don't know how to update the selected id because onclicking the update button 
it should navigate to main page and their corresponding values have to be filled in respective fields.when i tried to use **onnavigated** method to get the selected id record and if the page loads during startup it throws exception "no key was found"
in the line

> var n = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State ["list"];

how to make the application to load so that it does not consider the key.please help me to solve this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check to see if the key exists first:

```
if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("list") == true)
{
    n = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["list"];
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("list");
}
```

before trying to load it.